# Add list of characters to the start of column names in specific column ranges

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to add a list of 64 character stings (e.g. "m_news_ed_") to the *start* of a range of column names.

```
addToCol <- c("m_med_ed_","f_edu_vc_","m_gov_barr_","f_mil_gen_" ..."f_heal_stnur_")
```

So, the first item in the list needs to be added to the start of the column names in columns 3 to 11. Then, the second item needs to be added to the start of column names in 13 to 21. And so on, 62 more times.

If it helps, the column spacing is 10 columns each time. 3:11 then 13:21 then 23:31.

```
colRanges <- c(3:11, 13:21, 23:31 ... 633:641)
```

I was thinking a for loop but not too sure how I would go about cycling through both the list of column ranges and the list of characters to add in.

I have the code to be able to do each individual set of columns but this would take 64 lines of code

```
colnames(data)[3:11] <- paste("m_news_ed_",colnames(data[3:11]), sep = "_")
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Try `i1 <- unlist(Map(":", seq(3, 633, by = 10), seq(11, 641, by = 10))); names(data)[i1] <- paste0("m_news_ed_", names(data)[i1])`

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. However, your suggestion adds the same characters "m_news_ed_" to all the column ranges. I would need "m_news_ed_" for columns 3:11 and then then next characters "f_edu_vc_" to columns 13:21 and so on

Comment: In that case, you create a vector of names for the same, and replicate and paste iti i.e. `paste0(rep(addToCol, each = 10), names(data)[i1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` from `base R` to create the sequence from two sets of integers and then `paste` with the 'addToCol'

```
i1 <- unlist(Map(":", seq(3, 633, by = 10), seq(11, 641, by = 10)))
names(data)[i1] <- paste0(rep(addToCol, each = 10), names(data)[i1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about modifying your *add* vector. Then you can touch the *colnames* vector in one swoop.

```
    addToCol <- c("m_med_ed_","f_edu_vc_","m_gov_barr_","f_mil_gen_","f_heal_stnur_")
    addToCol2 <- ""   # start with a blank
    for (i in 1:length(addToCol)) {
        # add a blank, then the prefix nine times
        addToCol2 <- c(addToCol2, "", rep(addToCol[i], times = 9))
    }
    colnames(data) <- paste0(addToCol2, colnames(data))
```

Here's what you get.  I think it's right.

```
   > addToCol2
```

[1] ""              ""              "m_med_ed_"     "m_med_ed_"     "m_med_ed_"
 [6] "m_med_ed_"     "m_med_ed_"     "m_med_ed_"     "m_med_ed_"     "m_med_ed_"
[11] "m_med_ed_"     ""              "f_edu_vc_"     "f_edu_vc_"     "f_edu_vc_"
[16] "f_edu_vc_"     "f_edu_vc_"     "f_edu_vc_"     "f_edu_vc_"     "f_edu_vc_"
[21] "f_edu_vc_"     ""              "m_gov_barr_"   "m_gov_barr_"   "m_gov_barr_"
[26] "m_gov_barr_"   "m_gov_barr_"   "m_gov_barr_"   "m_gov_barr_"   "m_gov_barr_"
[31] "m_gov_barr_"   ""              "f_mil_gen_"    "f_mil_gen_"    "f_mil_gen_"
[36] "f_mil_gen_"    "f_mil_gen_"    "f_mil_gen_"    "f_mil_gen_"    "f_mil_gen_"
[41] "f_mil_gen_"    ""              "f_heal_stnur_" "f_heal_stnur_" "f_heal_stnur_"
[46] "f_heal_stnur_" "f_heal_stnur_" "f_heal_stnur_" "f_heal_stnur_" "f_heal_stnur_"
[51] "f_heal_stnur_"